# LoadRunner parameter having sub iteration

Tags: loadrunner

My task is to login with a user and enter 10 orders and  then logout.

Currently, I'm doing a user login > enter single order > logout. This way in the controller I'm using 10 users with 5 iteration so that's about 50 transactions.

Now, instead of entering a single order I need to enter 10 orders per user login.

Can you please suggest the best way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (ordercounter=1;ordercounter<=10;ordercounter++)
{   // my order code here which begins and ends at the same point }
```

Programming - Foundation skill set for any performance testing tool

Comment: I tired this but one challenge is, i'm using order values in parameters and for every loop in for condition the same values are being displayed, i want a unique value to be entered.

Comment: Then you need to break out the parameters into a unique set for each user.  See the Block Size assignment and unique.  Make sure to continue to cycle at the end of the data set so you can loop around with the subset.  Also, investigate the functions with allow you to advance the parameter programmatically and not just with each iteration